# Spring data very slow native query compared to raw SQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot App that uses Spring data JPA and is connecting to a PostgreSQL DB

I have the following method, with the associated query, in my repository:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Listing l WHERE l.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT l_b.listing_id FROM listing_booking l_b WHERE l_b.bookings_id IN (SELECT b.id FROM booking b WHERE ?1 <= b.enddate AND ?2 >= b.startdate))", nativeQuery = true)
List<Listing> findFreeListings(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);
```

This method will return all free listings for a specific timeframe. When I execute this on the DB directly, the time of execution is about 330ms. When this is executed by the Spring Boot app and therefore Spring Data JPA, I get a response after about 3500ms. I have run multiple tests, and results are very close to the values I just described.

The returned result set for the test query is about 370 rows.

The model for a Listing is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Listing extends BaseModel {
    // obj_nr
    private Integer objectId;

    // Other fields, no collections

    @OneToMany
    private List<Price> prices;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Booking> bookings;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Image> images;

    @OneToMany
    private List<File> files;

    @OneToMany
    private List<BookingRequest> bookingRequests;

}
```

I am trying to understand where the 10x increase is coming from. I am sure that converting the query to the correct instances might be quite "heavy", but it seems to me that it is not the only issue. The Hikari configuration for this connection is as follows:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    # ...
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 10 #maximum pool size
      connection-init-sql: SELECT 1
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
      auto-commit: true
      connection-timeout: 3000
      idle-timeout: 600000
      leak-detection-threshold: 45000
      max-lifetime: 1800000
      validation-timeout: 5000
```

Could it be that all the `@OneToMany` relationships are also fetched and therefore need to be converted? Or is there some test I might be able to run to understand where the time is lost?

**EDIT**: After being asked in the comments, I enabled the following properties:

```yaml
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

and indeed the queries for the linked entities are being fetched as well! So it may come down to these queries and the fact that Spring Data has to convert them all.

Also, I noticed something strange: I rebooted my laptop after a long time, and rerun the queries:

Spring Data: ~ 600ms
Direct execution: ~ 200ms

Although there is still a difference, its not as big as before.

Comment: can you enable hibernate/jpa sql statement logging to see whether there are additional statements issued?

Comment: Does the time measured for executing it directly include the time to fetch **ALL** rows?

Comment: @JensSchauder Yes the time includes all rows

Comment: @fladdimir I enabled logging, see the edit. I think it comes down to the fact that I have so many linked entities, and those are also eagerly fetched. I may have to delay the fetch, or just leave with a slower query